# Create a page in C# for editing data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, gridview

I am trying to create a page in C# for editing data in SQL Server, and the data is like `title`, `date`, `description` and that's not a big deal

The problem is each row of this has a foreign key to another table that has image URL so each row has like 3 OR more images.

Like I said before I want to create a page which can edit all of these, I made it with listview but it really really bad so I was trying to find another ideas so can you help me in that

Comment: What problem are you currently needing help with?  Code examples of a specific problem will give you a better chance of getting assistance.

Comment: am just trying to find a better idea than mine

Answer (score 0):

Well, the foreign key isn't that difficult to deal with. When a user edits that FK, before you allow the change to be committed to the cell or saved, run a check against the Db to see if their entry is valid. If it is, allow the edit, if not, cancel their edit of that value.

If that other table is the only table that has a FK to worry about, you could return just the Ids in your initial call and check against the dataset to save some round trips.